# How to find a basis for a linear space of polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Questions such like,

(1) Let $V = P^4$ be the vector space of all real valued polynomials of degree less than or equal to four. Let $W =\{p(x)\in P^3 |p(−2)=p(2)\}$. Find the basis for $W$

(2) Let $U = P^3$ be the vector space of all real valued polynomials of degree less than or equal to three. Let $W =\{p(x)\in P^3 |p(−1)=p(1)=0\}$. Find the basis for $W$

I don't know how I should start. The only step I know is that $P^4$ basis is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ and $P^3$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.  How should I proceed ?

Comment: Probably should read "find **a** basis".

Comment: What do $U,V$ have to do with anything?

Comment: The way to start is by understanding that there's no such thing as a "basis for a polynomial". What you are asking about is a basis for a *vector space*. In Linear Algebra, if you can't get the terminology right, you have zero chance of getting the concepts right, and of being able to do the problems.

Answer (score 1):

To find a basis for such a space you should take a generic polynomial of degree $3$ (i.e $p(x)=ax^{3}+b^{2}+cx+d$) and see what relations those impose on the coefficients. This will help you find a basis. For example for the first one we must have:

$-8a+4b-2c+d=8a+4b+2c+d$

so we must have $0=16a+4c$. This means once either $a$ or $c$ is specified then the other is determined. Notice that no conditions are imposed on $b$ and $d$. Hence, we can make a total of $3$ independent choices. Hence, one possible choice of basis would be $1, x^{2},x^{3}-4x$ which comes from choosing $d=1$, $b=1$ and $a=1$ respectively. You can verify that this is a basis. I have left the second problem for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as in the first answer, or you can try guessing and verifying.

An approach I like is to express the subspace as the null space of some operator. The form of the operator is often fairly clear from the question.

For the first, you are looking for a basis for the set of polynomials of degree 3 or less that satisfy the given condition. You know that $\dim P^3 = 4$, and the condition expresses one scalar constraint, so intuitively we expect that the dimension of $W$ will be three.

If we define the linear operator $L:P^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $Lp = p(2)-p(-2)$, we see that $W = \ker L$ and $\dim {\cal R}L = 1$ from which we confirm that $\dim \ker L = 4 -1 = 3$.

The even members (that is, the polynomials $x \mapsto 1$, $x \mapsto x^2$) of the basis you mentioned clearly lie in this space, so we need just one more element to form a basis. Try some combination $x \mapsto x+ax^3$, for this to satisfy the condition we need $2+8a = -2 - 8a$ or $a=-{1 \over 4}$. Hence the functions $x \mapsto 1$, $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto x - {1 \over 4} x^3$ from a basis for $W$.

For the second, let $H:\mathbb{P}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $H(p) = (p(-1), p(1))$. We see that $W = \ker H$. Since $H(x \mapsto (x-1)) = (-2,0)$ and $H(x \mapsto (x+1)) = (0,2)$, we see that $\dim {\cal R}H = 2$, and so
$\dim W = 4 - 2 = 2$. If a polynomial has roots $1,-1$, then we know that it must have a factor $x^2-1$, so we try that first to get $H(x \mapsto x^2-1) = (0,0)$. Similarly we have $H(x \mapsto x(x^2-1)) = (0,0)$, so the functions
$x \mapsto x^2-1$, $x \mapsto x^3-x$ form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Start with $U$. $U$ is the real linear space of polynomials whose orders do not exceed $3$ which vanish at $\pm 1$. Every such polynomial is divided by $x^{2}-1$. So, that means every $p\in U$ can be written as $(ax-b)(x^{2}-1)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real constants, which gives a basis for $U$ of $\{ x(x^{2}-1), (x^{2}-1) \}$. This set is linearly independent because the orders of all its member polynomials are all different.

Next look at $V$. If $p \in V$, then $p(x)-p(2)$ vanishes at $x=\pm 2$, which means that $p(x)-p(2)=(x^{2}-4)(ax^{2}+bx+c)$ for some constants $a$, $b$, $c$. That means a general such $p \in V$ can be written as $(ax^{2}+bx+c)(x^{2}-4)+d$. So $\{ x^{2}(x^{2}-4),x(x^{2}-4),x^{2}-4,1\}$ is a basis for $V$. As before, this set is a linearly-independent set because the elements are all of different orders.